# O que significa um numeral anterior à um operando dentro dos parênteses?

Tags: assembly, x86, pic, cpu

Estou estudando assembly, e encontrei códigos para trabalhar com displays TFT/LCD, e não encontrei informações sobre uma instrução em especifico, ela move múltiplos de uma cadeia de longo dos registradores de dados para o registrador de endereço, porém o registrador de endereço está dentro de parênteses precedido por um numeral.
O que essa instrução faz? E qual seria o nome dessa operação para que eu possa buscar mais informações sobre? Eu conheço o pré-incremento e pós-decremento e vice-versa, porém nunca havia visto essa instrução.
As partes em específico do código abaixo:

```
movem.l d0/d1/d2/d3, 4(a0)
(...)
movem.l 4(a0), d0/d1/d2/d3
(...)
move.l d7-d6, 0(a7)
(...)
move.l 0(a0), -(a7) ;aqui por exemplo, ele move o primeiro operando que eu não sei o que faz, para um pré-decremento de a7
(...)
move.l 2(a0), (a7)+ ;e aqui para um pós-incremento de a7
(...)
move.b d2, 2(d0)
```

Comment: Isso é fora do padrão usado nas 2 notações mais comuns ou nem é do x86.

Comment: É assembly para Microcontroladores, e o _8086_ provavelmente não precisa de incremento/decremento de memória pois possuí as instruções **inc** e **dec** que substituem o `addq.b #1, %registrador%`, colocando em nível lógico alto o **carry in** ou **borrow in** respectivamente. O código compila perfeitamente, porém se eu remover, por exemplo o 0(a0), deixando apenas a0, as informações no display LCD 160x128 modelo T6963C, não são exibidas.
Infelizmente o datasheet do Zilog Z8L18020FSG não possuí nenhuma referência sobre isso.